# find the correlation coefficient of two random variables after the same function transformation

Tags: transformation, uniform-distribution, covariance, correlation, bivariate-distributions

we have two random variables: U1 and U2 follow uniform distribution between 0 and 1:

U1 ~ U(0,1), U2 ~ U(0,1)

and correlation: corr(U1,U2) = ρ

covariance : cov(U1,U2) = corr(U1,U2)/12

Then we do the following transformation:
L1 = -ln(1-U1), L2 = -ln(1-U2)

How to calculate the correlation coefficient or the covariance between L1 and L2? Please help!

Comment: Is $\rho$ meant to be the correlation $\operatorname{corr}(U_1,\,U_2)$, or the covariance $\operatorname{cov}(U_1,\,U_2)=\operatorname{corr}(U_1,\,U_2)/12$? Edit that into your question. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a formatting guide.

Comment: Thx, I've edited.